# Subscribe calling multiple time angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, behaviorsubject

I have this navigation bar

```
  <span (click)="routing('settings')">
       Settings
  </span>
```

> in ts file

```
 routing(data) {
    let jsons = {
      UserId: this.UserId,
      Nav: data,
    };
    this.Service.List.next(jsons);
  }
```

in service file

```
List= new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
```

when i click on settings menu subscribe it in next component oninit method

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.Service.List.subscribe(response => {
       console.log('function called ');
 } 
}
```

Issue is sometime ngOnInit is not called still subscribe method is called multiple times upto 10-15 times, i want to resolve this issue if i click on navigation bar link it should subscribe only once, this happend only when subscribe gets called before ngOninit.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Unclear question, I guess you just need to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 2):

Since your service has a longer lifetime than your component, you have to cleanup your subscriptions every time your component gets destroyed:

```
destroy$ = new Subject<void>()
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.Service.List.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(response => {
       console.log('function called ');
 } 
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.destroy$.next()
}
```

`ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` are guaranteed to be called exactly once per component lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I think in that case you can use RxJs **take** operator.

```
this.Service.List.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks i tried it with `take('1')`  then subscribe was not working then changed value to `take(5)` then it is working, what changes i have to make in my code

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any type. Use camelCase convention of variable names. In your service:

```
interface IData {
  userId: number;
  nav: string;   
}

class ListService {
  private list$ = new BehaviorSubject<IData>(null);
  getList(): Observable<IData> {
    return this.list$.asObservable().pipe(sharedReplay(1));
  }
  setList(data: IData): void {
    this.list$.next(data);
  }
}
```

In .ts file:

```
routing(nav: string): void {
  const jsons = {
     userId: this.UserId,
     nav,
  };
  this.service.setList(jsons);
}
```

In component class:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getList
    .subscribe(console.log); // your data
}
```

I guess it will help.